# MAMP PRO 6.9, PHP 8.2.0, Mac 14.21 and Mongo DB - Apache Fails

Tags: php, mongodb, macos

Have been trying to get MongoDB installed on MAMP PRO 6.9, PHP 8.2.0, Mac 14.21 via PECL but after a successful install and enabling the extension, when restarting MAMP Pro, Apache fails and none of my sites are available.

Disabling the extension doesn't help and I have to delete it and reinstall MAMP Pro to get back to normal.

Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Nigel

I tried re-installing the extension, Google-searched extensively.

Comment: Did you read the error logs ?

Comment: Yes - but all I get in the Apache error log is:

[Mon Mar 11 08:28:40.363985 2024] [:alert] [pid 73011] (22)Invalid argument: FastCGI: read() from pipe failed (0)
[Mon Mar 11 08:28:40.364200 2024] [:alert] [pid 73011] (22)Invalid argument: FastCGI: the PM is shutting down, Apache seems to have disappeared - bye

So nothing useful :-(

Comment: The weird thing is, even having the extension in the 'no-debug' directory stops Apache from loading even if the extension is not enabled.